# Can on click and on window load work from a script loaded using $.getScript() in jQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery

Can on click and on window load work from a script loaded using [$.getScript()](https://api.jquery.com/jquery.getscript/) in jQuery?

My loading script is:

```
jQuery( document ).ready( function($) {

    $.getScript('scripts-loaded.js');

});
```

scripts-loaded.js (not wrapped in document.ready as the loading script already has this):

```
// This works

$('link[rel=stylesheet]').each( function() {

    var href = $(this).attr('href');
    href += (href.match(/\?/) ? '&' : '?') + Date.now();
    $(this).attr('href', href);

});

// This doesn't 

$('body').on( 'click', '#test', function(e) {

    e.preventDefault();
    alert('the click worked');

});

// This doesn't 

$(window).load( function() {
    alert('the window load worked');
});
```

Comment: We need to see the html. `$('body').on( 'click', '#test', function(e) {` should work assuming only ONE id="test" on the page. It is not needed to delegate if id="test" is already on the page when getScript is executed

Comment: The page might have finished loading in the meantime, so I would not expect `$(window).load` to work reliably in this scenario. Why the body click handler should not work though, can not be explained by what you have shown so far.

Comment: the html code is just a single test link in the page with the #test id in the standard <head><body> markup

Comment: Try to link script in html head if possible instead of getScript() and then use ready function in scripts-loaded.js

Comment: Click works just fine with your code, I just tested this.